# Get JSON-Array from a Form with jQuery and serializearray()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try now to create an Array with JQuery but my Arrays are wrong and it not this what i need.

I need an Array with single Value from list members, children and multiple values from class="extra".

How can I get Values from data-attribute with Jquery - serializearray()

```
<form>
<select name="members">
<option data-name="Tom" data-age="43">Tom</option>
<option data-name="Tim" data-age="33">Tim</option>
</select>

<select name="children">
<option data-name="Tom" data-age="4">Tom</option>
<option data-name="Tim" data-age="9">Tim</option>
</select>


<label for="1"><input type="checkbox" class="extra" data-love="dog" data-size="big" class="box" id="1"></label>
<label for="2"><input type="checkbox" class="extra" data-love="dog" data-size="small" class="box" id="2"></label>
<label for="3"><input type="checkbox" class="extra" data-love="cat" data-size="big" class="box" id="3"></label>
<label for="4"><input type="checkbox" class="extra" data-love="cat" data-size="small" class="box" id="4"></label>
<button name="send">Ok</button>
</form>
```

I need an Array like this

```
$array = [
    "members" => ["name" => "Tom", "age" => "43"],
    "children" => ["name" => "Tim", "age" => "7"],
    "extra" => ["love" => "Dog", "size" => "Big"],
    "extra" => ["love" => "Cat", "size" => "Small"]
];
```

How can I do it?

Comment: 1) There is no evidence of your own efforts to solve this problem. What have you done so far? 2) Since you tagged the question with javascript, your `$array` is obviously not `javascript`. It would be of great help, if you improve on that.

Comment: Why is `$array` obviously not JavaScript? `$` is a legal character to start an identifier in JavaScript, and jQuery is entirely JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

My solution.

```
$("#sendbutton").click(function () {
  var array = {};
  var memName = $("form > #members option:selected").data("name");
  var memAge = $("form > #members option:selected").data("age");
  var chldName = $("form > #children option:selected").data("name");
  var chldAge = $("form > #children option:selected").data("age");
  var extName = $("form > .extra option:selected").data("love");
  var extSize = $("form > .extra option:selected").data("size");

  array.memberName = memName;
  array.memberAge = memAge;
  array.chldName = chldName;
  array.chldAge = extSize;

  var extName = [];
  var extSize = [];

  $('form > label > .modcheck:checked').each(function () {
   var name = $(this).data("name");
   var age = $(this).data("age");
   extName.push(name);
   extAge.push(age);
  });

  array.extName = extName;
  array.extAge = extAge;

  $.ajax({
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
   dataType: 'json',
   type: 'POST',
   url: "my-data.php",
   cache: false,
   data: JSON.stringify(array),
   success: function (result) {
   $("body").html(result);
   myUpdate();
  }
 });
 });
```

Output of my-data.php.

```
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($array);
 echo '</pre>';
```

In Firebug i get this Answer.

```
 <pre>Array
 (
   [memName] => Tom
   [memAge] => 43
   [childName] => Tim
   [childAge] => 7
   [extraName] => Array
       (
           [0] => Dog
           [1] => Cat
       )

   [extSize] => Array
       (
           [0] => Big
           [1] => Small
       )
  )
```

It works!
Does anyone have any idea how I can improve this code?